# Icecast + HTTPS disconnects after 3 seconds

Tags: https, icecast

I have a server that, not all times, kicks the users after 3 seconds when using a HTTPS connection.

- Valid TLS certificate.
- Icecast version 2.4.3.
- CentOS 7.5
- OpenSSL 1.0.2k

If I restart, backs to normal. But everytime I auto-renew my SSL Cert (Let's Encrypt), every 80 days, I need to manually test the server... if I "wget" the URL, no problem, it downloads for minutes...

Right now (12/02/2018) the problem is happening:

https://audio8.97fm.com.br/energia

Any ideia?

---

To TBR:

```
[2018-12-03  09:45:58] INFO source/source_main listener count on /energia now 1
[2018-12-03  09:45:58] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update global listeners (1)
[2018-12-03  09:45:58] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update global clients (3)
[2018-12-03  09:45:58] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update "/energia" listeners (1)
[2018-12-03  09:46:00] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update "/energia2" total_bytes_read (824239981)
[2018-12-03  09:46:00] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update "/energia2" total_bytes_sent (11441133)
[2018-12-03  09:46:02] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update global clients (4)
[2018-12-03  09:46:02] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update global connections (50399)
[2018-12-03  09:46:02] DBUG auth/add_listener_to_source max on /energia is 2200 (cur 1)
[2018-12-03  09:46:02] DBUG auth/add_listener_to_source Added client to /energia
[2018-12-03  09:46:02] DBUG auth/add_authenticated_listener client authenticated, passed to source
[2018-12-03  09:46:02] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update global client_connections (48325)
[2018-12-03  09:46:02] DBUG source/source_main Client added for mountpoint (/energia)
[2018-12-03  09:46:02] INFO source/source_main listener count on /energia now 2
[2018-12-03  09:46:03] DBUG format/format_check_http_buffer processing pending client headers
[2018-12-03  09:46:03] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update "/energia" listeners (2)
[2018-12-03  09:46:03] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update global listeners (2)
[2018-12-03  09:46:03] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update global listener_connections (46030)
[2018-12-03  09:46:03] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update "/energia" total_bytes_read (1101800)
[2018-12-03  09:46:03] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update "/energia" total_bytes_sent (1201852)
[2018-12-03  09:46:03] DBUG client/client_send_bytes Client connection died
[2018-12-03  09:46:03] DBUG source/source_main Client removed
[2018-12-03  09:46:03] INFO source/source_main listener count on /energia now 1
[2018-12-03  09:46:03] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update global listeners (1)
[2018-12-03  09:46:03] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update global clients (3)
[2018-12-03  09:46:03] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update "/energia" listeners (1)
[2018-12-03  09:46:05] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update "/energia2" total_bytes_read (824260982)
[2018-12-03  09:46:05] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update "/energia2" total_bytes_sent (11441133)
[2018-12-03  09:46:07] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update global clients (4)
[2018-12-03  09:46:07] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update global connections (50400)
[2018-12-03  09:46:07] DBUG auth/add_listener_to_source max on /energia is 2200 (cur 1)
[2018-12-03  09:46:07] DBUG auth/add_listener_to_source Added client to /energia
[2018-12-03  09:46:07] DBUG auth/add_authenticated_listener client authenticated, passed to source
[2018-12-03  09:46:07] DBUG source/source_main Client added for mountpoint (/energia)
[2018-12-03  09:46:07] INFO source/source_main listener count on /energia now 2
[2018-12-03  09:46:08] DBUG format/format_check_http_buffer processing pending client headers
[2018-12-03  09:46:08] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update global client_connections (48326)
[2018-12-03  09:46:08] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update "/energia" listeners (2)
[2018-12-03  09:46:08] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update global listeners (2)
[2018-12-03  09:46:08] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update global listener_connections (46031)
[2018-12-03  09:46:08] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update "/energia" total_bytes_read (1121400)
[2018-12-03  09:46:08] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update "/energia" total_bytes_sent (1235865)
[2018-12-03  09:46:08] DBUG client/client_send_bytes Client connection died
[2018-12-03  09:46:08] DBUG source/source_main Client removed
```

Answer (score 1):

We've had reports of problems on CentOS 7 with its openSSL. I *think* we traced it back to some sort of openSSL issue in that particular distro version. So one thing would be to try a newer openSSL.

Could you please check the Icecast `error.log`? If necessary increase to log level 4 and reload/HUP.

For me attempting to access the stream with curl breaks reproducibly:

```
< icy-url:http://www.97fm.com.br
< 
{ [5 bytes data]
100 15399    0 15399    0     0   3689      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--  3690
* Closing connection 0
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
} [2 bytes data]
```

Comment: Hello TBR, no error logged in error.log (default config). I can change level to 4 but if I HUP it, will be back to normal. The problem does not happen all times, only when I restart it, after a SSL cert renew. But I can try keep restarting until the problem happen again, to check the logs... helps?

Comment: A `kill -HUP $PID` should only change the configuration and not do a full restart. It might make the problem go away, but more likely will leave it in place.

Comment: Note: I have 2 PP, /energia (main) and /energia2 (fallback) from different encoders. If needed I can provide the config. But I don't think this is related.

Comment: could you maybe add that to your question? would be much more readable that way. Thanks!

Comment: The relevant line seems to be "DBUG client/client_send_bytes Client connection died". Which is most likely the openSSL problem.

Comment: Yes, original message updated with logs. Do you know if the problem is only related to CentOS? Fedora is affected too?